# Call back function is not working node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, electron

I am trying to build login system using node.js and i am stuck in this call back function error i have managed to build get login info and check them with data base but when i am verifying password it's taking some time so in there i need to use call back function but even i used callback function it's giving me the same error which is since validation or database call taking time it's executing other stuff in the in my case if conditions.
 i have tried to implement this another way just tried to console.log order and all executing opposite this my result first

this is the order that it's run 
**3
2
undefined
1**
but i need run this exactly opposite should i use promises instead of callback?

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
const Password = require("node-php-password");
const connection = require("./connection");

var hash;
var done;
var self = module.exports = {
   getuser_information:function(user_name,pwd,callback){

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM `super_admin` WHERE ad_un = ?", user_name, function(err, result, fildes) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let numbers_retuned = result.length;
        hash = result[0].desk;
        console.log(1);

    });
    callback(hash,self.true_or_not);
},
hashverif:function(hash,true_or_not){
    true_or_not();
    console.log(2);
},
true_or_not:function(){
    console.log(3);
    return 1

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE after your comment

***You have two errors***

1. Your  `get_stored_password`  function returns nothing when your callback function is called that's why `console.log(function_returning_nothing())` outputs `undefined`

---

2. You forgot to pass `done` to your callback function in
       `get_stored_password`'s definition `callback(done)`

   ```
   const {
       ipcMain
   } = require('electron');
   const Password = require("node-php-password");
   const connection = require("./connection");

   var hash;
   var done;
   var self = module.exports = {
       get_stored_password: function(name, pwd, callback) {
           connection.query("SELECT * FROM `super_admin` WHERE ad_un = ?", name, function(err, result, fildes) {
               if (err) throw err;
               let numbers_retuned = result.length;
               hash = result[0].desk;

               if (numbers_retuned == 1) {
                   var test = pwd;
                   done = Password.verify(test, hash);



               } else {
                   console.log('no');
                   return 0;
               }


               //you must pass an argument to your callback function
               // and return done var to get an output when you log this function
               callback(done);
               return done;
           });

       },
       chek_if_true: function(done) {
           console.log(done);
           if (done) {
               return true;

           } else {
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

That's why when you log `done` to the console it's `undefined`

Comment: your correct after adding that it returned true but it's from console log inside the chek_if_true but i am calling this function from main.js when i am calling the function from main.js it's returns a undefined  :-(

Comment: `console.log(login.get_stored_password('Thaali_Super_Admin',"password123",login.chek_if_true));
` this is the calling from main.js and for this call it's return a undefined

Comment: your  `get_stored_password`  function returns nothing when your callback function is called that's why `console.log(function_returning_nothing())` outputs `undefined`

Comment: sorry for asking but to where should i put return in get_stored_password it's i am little confused please help i have tried this and that also not working ` var re = callback(done);
        console.log(re);
        if(re){
            return 1;
        }`

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply's still the same error it's calling other function's before finishing some other function i am trying here if the returned value is 1 /true then the user is a valid user if not user is not valid. i will re-cheek my codding......

Comment: Javascript asynchronous behavior

Comment: yep but i need to do this exactly in order

Comment: @ThalindaBandara [Understanding Asynchronous JavaScript Callbacks Through Household Chores](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-through-household-chores-e3de9a1dbd04)